# How to run a command in the background?

Tags: linux, process, jobs

How would you run `man -df` in the background properly?

When I try

```
ping man -df > /dev/null
```

it goes through at first it gives me a PID number but then it says

```
ping unknown host man
```

and it doesn't list anything in the jobs.

If I just try

```
man -df &
```

it just runs it.

Comment: The question becomes clearer if one notices that the questioner is running `man -df` not `man df`, and makes no mention of setting `tostop`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `ping` a manpage! What does `ping` do?

```
NAME
       ping, ping6 - send ICMP ECHO_REQUEST to network hosts
```

Some links for further reading:
**[whatis](http://www.linfo.org/whatis.html)**
**[manpages](http://www.linfo.org/man.html)**
**[send process to background](https://serverfault.com/questions/41959/how-to-send-jobs-to-background-without-stopping-them#41965)**

Comment: You have mis-read the question and not explained an important part (at the end of the question) that the questioner does not understand.

Comment: @JdeBP Thanks, I missed the `-`. I'll remove the part about `df` in my post.